# How to pick the particular id from table data

Tags: selenium

I want pick the particular id from table, table have 10 rows and 7 columns,and i am using selenium rc and eclipse ide, when i ran below code its giving below error pls tell me any one

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Invalid target format. Correct format is tableName.rowNum.columnNum


int rowCount= selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='role']/tbody/tr/").intValue();
System.out.println("Row Count Is As " + rowCount);
int colCount= selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='role']/tbody/tr[1]/td").intValue();
System.out.println("Col Count Is As " + colCount);

String myInput = "3";
for(int j = 1; j<rowCount; j++)
 {
   String myroleID = selenium.getTable("//table[@id='role'].["+j+"].1");
   if(myroleID.equals(myInput))
    {
    System.out.println("Given Input is in the Row:"+j);

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is

```
selenium.getTable("role."+j+".1");
```

That should make it work